# In Python, how to signal other processes to terminate when a condition is met?

Tags: python, signals, python-multiprocessing

I am creating a multiprocess card game in Python where each user runs a function indefinitely to satisfy the winning condition. All the processes start execution parallelly. Once a user (process) has met the winning condition, I want it to command the other processes to stop execution and terminate.

I suspect the **signal** module in Python is useful for doing this. But I don't understand how to make a running program detect a signal from some other program. Basically, I want to do this -

```
# This is in the body of the function which is being run by all processes

while True:

    # perform some operations        

    if win_condition is True:
          terminate other running users (processes)
          break
```

How do I implement this?

Comment: Are you using `multiprocessing` for this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes. The users are objects of the class *Player*. This player class has a function which runs the main logic of the game. I'm using multiprocessing.Process() to start that driver function of each object.

Comment: You can use `Event` object from multiprocessing module